# Move Multiple sequence file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, move

I want to move sequence 20 file in different folder
so i use below code to move file but not work...

```
echo "Moving {$(( $j*20 -19))..$(( $j*20 ))}.png ------- > Folder $i"
mv {$(( $j*20 -19))..$(( $j*20 ))}.png $i;
```

So i get output in terminal

```
Moving {1..20}.png ------- > Folder 1
mv: cannot stat ‘{1..20}.png’: No such file or directory
```

But there is already 1.png to 20.png image file + Folder...
So how to move sequence file like

```
{1..20}.png -> Folder 1
{21..40}.png -> Folder 2
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to combine brace expansion with arithmetic expressions as you are doing. Specifically, ranges like `{a..b}` must contain literal values, not variables.

I would suggest that instead, you used a `for` loop:

```
for ((n=j*20-19;n<=j*20;++n)); do mv "$n.png" "$i"; done
```

The disadvantage of the above approach is that `mv` is called many times, rather than once. As suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471145/move-multiple-sequence-file-using-bash/26471188#comment41580701_26471188) (thanks [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)), you could use an array to reduce the number of calls:

```
files=()
for ((n=j*20-19;n<=j*20;++n)); do files+=( "$n.png" ); done
mv "${files[@]}" "$i"
```

`"${files[@]}"` is the full contents of the array, so all of the files are moved in one call to `mv`.

Comment: I would bundle up multiple file names in an array first, to minimize the number of calls to `mv`. Inside the `for` loop, `files+=( "$n.png" )`, then following the loop `mv "${files[@]}" "$i"`.

Comment: @Milllenium I mainly look at [this guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) as a reference but there are others out there too. Related to the discussion beneath the other answer, the [page on `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) explains why it's not the favoured approach.

Answer (score -1):

You have to evaluate the resulting string again with `eval`
For example

```
eval "mv {$(( $j*20 -19))..$(( $j*20 ))}.png folder$j"
```

Comment: The use of `eval` is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Thats new to me. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Because it is rarely necessary, and is too easily misused to execute code you did not intended to execute.

Comment: Yes it is working and a cleaner solution than the loop in my opinion. Though the concerns in terms of security are valid. So use it with care or stick to another solution.